# Cannot print string with std::end

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, ubuntu

I am having trouble with printing a string in C++.

I know there are lots of topics about this matter on SO, but most say to include `<string>`, `<iostream>` or `namespace std`. But I did all of that but still encounter the issue. Here is my code and the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//...
void affiche_date(int annee, int nbjours) {
    string mois;
    if (nbjours>31) {
         mois = "avril";
         nbjours -= 31;
    } else {
        mois = "avril";
    }
    cout << "Date de Paques en " << annee << " : " << nbjours << " " << mois << end;
}

int main() {
    int annee ( demander_annee() ) ;
    int jour ( date_paques(annee) );
    affiche_date(annee, jour);
}
```

Here is the error I get when I compile:

```
"error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’)"
```

This error is coming from the line with the cout in the function I gave you.

I am using Geany on linux Ubuntu and using c++11.

Thanks for you help

Comment: I think you meant `std::endl`

Comment: You forgot a letter. Voting to close as typo. ("endl" in your book is *not*  a typo. Only The Dane knows why it's spelled that way.)

Comment: you also have function definitons inside main - thats not right

Comment: @pm100: Those are declarations that stray really close to the most vexing parse. `annee` and `jour` are declared as integers that are initialized with the result of the function calls in parentheses. Edit: [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L5XnaDC3TxAws4kR)

Comment: @AndyG oh yes you are right. They just look so wrong

Comment: Thanks everyone, I fell stupid as indeed it was a typo for endl. 
I've been looking at this for an hour... Since it is the first time I tried cout with a string and I saw many people having the same issue I assumed it came from there. 
Sorry and thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @molbdnilo: It's a typo, but it feels like this won't be the first time someone makes this innocent mistake. I wonder if we can reword the title to be more relevant instead?

Comment: It's off topic but i'am trying to learn, so why do you annee and jour should be declared differently> They are initialized with the value returned by values returned by other functions. It works but it should not be done?

Comment: @AndyG Could be an idea, I can't even find a dupe. Something about "trying to print newline with `std::end"`?

Comment: @molbdnilo -- `endl` is short for **end of line**, just as `ends` its short for **end of string**.

Comment: @A.david Regarding the declaration style: you will sooner or later encounter the [Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work) and spend ages trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is not very clear yet but I'm going to read about this issue so I'll try not to fall in the trap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) is a function for getting an iterator to the end of a container.

You meant to use the [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) stream manipulator instead.

Note: avoid `using namespace std;` in your actual code, either take advantage of `using` directives to bring in only what you need, or favor qualifying names with their namespaces, like I have here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said it was only a typo...
But what you said is interesting. Could you please explain me why not to use using namespace std? I used it only because I am following a tutorial and they say to use it

Comment: @A.david https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: great. Thanks for your help